# Sigma-algebra generated by one to one function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Nice measurable space is defined as follows in Durrett's *Probability: Theory and Examples*:

> $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ is said to be nice if there is a 1-1 map $\varphi$ from $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ are both measurable.

Does this imply the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\varphi$ is equal to $\mathcal{F}$?

I think it is true in an easier case, where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ is the real line equipped with Borel measure, $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$, and $\varphi$ is strictly increasing instead of merely one-to-one. A short proof can be:
Fix x in $\mathbb{R}$. If $\omega \leq x$, then $\varphi(\omega) \leq \varphi(x)$, so $\omega \in \varphi^{-1}((-\infty,x])$. If $\omega > x$, then $\varphi(w) > \varphi(x)$, so $\omega \notin \varphi^{-1}((-\infty,x])$. This shows $\{\omega: \omega \leq x\} = \varphi^{-1}((-\infty,\varphi(x)])$. Since $\{(-\infty,x]: x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ generates $\mathcal{B}$, $\sigma(\varphi) = \mathcal{B}$.

---

On a second thought, the above can be generalized. Fix $E$ in $\mathcal{F}$. By the hypothesis $\varphi^{-1}$ is measurable, I think Durrett assumes $\varphi^{-1}$ exists so $\varphi$ is 1-1 and onto. Then $\varphi(E) = (\varphi^{-1})^{-1}(E)$. Since $\varphi^{-1}$ is measurable,$\varphi(E)$ is Borel. Since $\varphi$ is 1-1, $E = \varphi^{-1}(\varphi(E))$. So any set in $\mathcal{F}$ is in $\sigma(\varphi)$, this shows $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \sigma(\varphi)$. Also $\mathcal{F} \supseteq \sigma(\varphi)$. So $\mathcal{F} =\sigma(\varphi)$.
Is this correct?